# "По-одному" - через дефис?

Tags: орфография, грамотная-речь

Почему "сидели по-одному" через дефис?

Answer (score 5):

В Вашем примере ошибка - *сидели по одному* должно быть раздельно, без дефиса, так как это предлог с числительным.

Но откуда ошибка - понятно: кем-то этот предлог с числительным был воспринят как наречие ("По-одному пахли мох и вода, по-другому― неясно и терпко― осоки").

[Орфографический словарь](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83&all=x)

> по-одному, нареч. (сначала по-одному, а потом - по-другому)
>
> по одному (поодиночке, следуя друг за другом)